# Reading SQL from local files, then eval-ing it. Safe?

Tags: mysql, perl

I've inherited code that has very large SQL queries within code, typically within heredocs and with variables interpolated that will dynamically select a table or fields, like this:

```
    my $query = <<"SQL";
SELECT foo
FROM $some_table
WHERE bar = 'baz'
SQL
```

Some of the SQL queries are quite large. The issue is that this makes my Perl files unnecessarily long and difficult to read. Code analysis and highlighting tools can't parse the heredoc SQL, either.

I'd like to keep SQL in actual SQL files and change Perl code like the above to read a file from the local directory:

```
my $query = eval(get_sql('some-file.sql'));
```

... `eval`-ing it so that all in-scope vars are expanded.

Some of this would take place in web accessible scripts where users are passing parameters. Absolutely all variables are cleaned, and I use paramaterized statements in all criteria clauses (WHERE, AND, etc.)

There's a lot of FUD about using `eval()`, so I'd like to know: Is my solution safe to use in a web application?

*EDIT*...
I should mention further that the `get_sql()` function might look something like this:

```
sub get_sql {
    my ($filename) = @_;

    my $sql = slurp("/path/to/file/$filename.sql");
    my $query = qq|return qq{| . $sql . qq|};|;
    return $query;
}
```

I understand that the quote operators can't appear in the SQL string that will be returned.

*EDIT2*...
This is an eminently reasonable question given any number of use cases and/or constraints. Downvotes... not warranted, folks.

Comment: `sql-server` or `mysql`?

Comment: Instead of using a file for your sql why not use stored procedures? Then your sql code is in the database where it belongs.

Comment: If you only want to expand variables, you can keep them in a hash and just `s/\$(\w+)/$variables{$1}/g`.

Comment: I should clarify that this is MySQL, not SQL Server. I originally included that tag because I thought it was for generic "SQL servers", not the ill-named Microsoft product, though the question concerns a general principle and the actual database probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use stored procedures for reasons that are neither here nor there. I'm concerned with the safety of the method described above.

Comment: Agreed, the specific DBMS doesn't matter. Use stored procedures and save yourself all the anguish. I can come up with exactly zero logical reasons for not using stored procedures.

Comment: As to the safety....well...since it sounds like you are now building up strings and executing them the safety is certainly in question. Are you at least parameterizing users values? Who has access to these files? There are many questions around this approach from a safety perspective.

Comment: Yes, all criteria clause variables are parameterized. Interpolated variables, e.g. for dynamically selecting a table in a SQL statement, are all filtered for expected content, or come from discrete sets.

Comment: What happens if large-query.sql is called multiple times? Are you caching the file loaded or reading it in multiple times?

Comment: It sometimes will be called multiple times. For example, the SQL file will be read over and over again within loops that are creating static resources, or doing other work. No matter the particulars, this is OK from a performance standpoint and I have no plans to cache.

Comment: *"`eval`-ing it so that all in-scope vars are expanded"* Do you really need that functionality? How do you imagine that an extra `eval` will help? What you're proposing sounds like a nightmare if dependencies. I think a template tool would serve you better, where you can pass the exact values to be interpolated in the call to render. And please don't use `qq|return qq{|` when `'return qq{'` will do fine.

Comment: Not an extra `eval`, merely an `eval`. No `eval`, then no variable expansion. That's why I'm using it.

Some of the SQL queries are absurdly large and have 50+ variables to expand. Identifying them and passing them to a template is technically possible but not practical. Using an `eval` from the calling script will expand everything in scope, which is what I need.

Comment: @dmc7z: I am sure that you will find a way to justify an unsafe method: I really don't know why you're asking for advice. Just be sure to put your name on the edits to the code.

Comment: *"Downvotes... not warranted, folks"* I don't think that's for you to judge. You came here asking for a prescribed answer and didn't get it. You don't understand computer security and you need to start learning that it's not about "it looks fine to me".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters,

```
my $query = <<"SQL";
SELECT foo
FROM $some_table
WHERE bar = 'baz'
SQL
```

suffers from an injection bug. It should be

```
my $some_table_lit = $dbh->quote_identifier($some_table);

my $query = <<"SQL";
SELECT foo
FROM $some_table_lit
WHERE bar = 'baz'
SQL
```

Your template system is completely crappy. It's the CS equivalent of hammering a screw. It makes it really easy to write unsafe code (as you've already done), it introduce high coupling, and makes the code very fragile.

You should use a better templating system than the one you are currently using (with or without `eval`).

What follows is an example using [Template-Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template):

```
my $tt = Template->new();

$tt->process('some-file.sql', {
   some_table => $dbh->quote_identifier($some_table),
})
   or die $template->error();
```

```
SELECT foo
FROM [% some_table %]
WHERE bar = 'baz'
```

Comment: This is probably my backup solution. I do use Template Toolkit and I appreciate the suggestion. I am interested in knowing the particular circumstances under which the eval()-ing solution is unsafe, however.

Comment: Thanks. The variables that expand to field and table names are always defined in the code and never reflect raw user input, so I think they're safe, but it's probably good to use the $dbh method as a habit. Point taken.

Comment: wut. You're going to do it wrong because you think it's safe? Always convert text into whatever you are inserting in into (SQL, HTML, URL params, `sh`, etc, etc, etc).  As you saw, it's not any harder doing it right! (Given that you made two mistakes using `eval`, I would argue it's much easier doing it right!)

Comment: @dmc7z: All code is guilty until proven to be innocent: you should be assuming that your code is unsafe unless you can prove otherwise. Such a proof is a little easier if you use a template system, but asking for examples of how any given approach may be unsafe is wrong-thinking.